# trying to turn on an led with arduino for x seconds

Tags: arduino

My code is suppose to take in 2 numbers: `num1` and `num2`. Then it should turn on the built in led for `num1` seconds and then blink the led for `num2` seconds. Should be a very simple program but for some reason the led will not turn on. Here is my code:

```
long num1 = 0;
long num2 = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
```

```
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  while (Serial.available() == 0) {
  }
  bool d = true;
  while (d) {
    num1 = Serial.parseInt();
    delay(2);
    if (num1 > 0) {
      d = false;
    }
  }

  bool c = true;
  while (c) {
    num2 = Serial.parseInt();
    delay(2);
    if (num2 > 0) {
      c = false;
    }
  }

  // num1=5;
  // num2=4;

  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  delay(num1 * 1000);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  delay(1500);

  for (int i = 0; i < num2; i++) {
    // delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    delay(500);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you wired up the LED the right way round? What happens if you comment out all the serial reading stuff and just set num1 and num2?

Comment: I am not wiring any leds I am using the one that is built into the board if i comment out the serial stuff it works perfectly

Comment: @Roddy any idea why that won't work

Comment: No, but the problem's obviously in your serial code and nothing to do wit the LED... Put some `serial.write("got here")` lines in to see where it's getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that the LED_BUILTIN corresponds to your board?

Try setting it manually to e.g. 13 for a regular nano